# Why can not the browser url be gotten from a dialog window (Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Salvete!  I have a function in one of my js files that fetches the url from the main browser window.  My addon is a toolbar.  This function works fine when called from the toolbar's javascript.

However, I also have another dialog window (via xul) that uses this function (it is called via a window load listener), but when it is called, although the function does fire, it gives me this: `TypeError: window.content is null`.

```
function GetTheBrowserUrl(){
var browserwindow = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
return browserwindow;
//return getBrowser().contentWindow.location.href;
}
```

So how can I get this to work from the dialog window?  It seems like calling the function from the dialog window needs to get a handle on the browser window somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var window = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
return window.gBrowser.contentWindow.location.href
```